# При изменении свойства, не изменяется значение привязанного элемента WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Создал свойство

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private  int _progressValue;
    public int progressValue
    {
        get => _progressValue;
        set
        {
            _progressValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(progressValue));
        }
    }
```

И создал прогрессбар:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="downbar" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Path=progressValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Но при попытке изменить свойство из класса MainWindow например свойство меняется, но вот на прогрессбаре ничего не меняется. Как сделать чтобы работало? Мне потом в это свойство нужно будет передавать значение из события по загрузке. Но щас пытаюсь хоть что-то передать из другого класса.
Менять пытаюсь так:

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        MainWindowViewModel mwvm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        mwvm.progressValue = 30;
        Console.WriteLine(mwvm.progressValue);
    }
```

Если что на всякий случай код из BaseViewModel:

```
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

На всякий вот структура моего франкенштейна или как там:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 экземпляра вьюмодели, один показываете, второй меняете. А надо один.

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainWindowViewModel vm = MainWindowViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;
    vm.progressValue = 30;
    Debug.WriteLine(vm.progressValue);
}
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Благодаря вам пытаюсь идти по стопам развития и вот разбираюсь в свойствах, привязках. Это действительно делает жизнь гораздо проще, огромное спасибо!

Comment: @АлександрКучеров Код, вносящий изменения надо лучше не в окне писать, а в самой вьюмодели. Поищите как к кнопкам команды прикручивать вместо обработчиков клика, я здесь раз 20 публиковал решение. Класс для команд RelayCommand, через делегаты, посмотрите в моих ответах у меня в профиле, я с телефона, мне неудобно искать.

Comment: Сейчас обязательно найду, спасибо большое!